# GPS signal sharing between android apps

Tags: android, gps

When testing my GPS tracking application, there is a problem with another GPS tracking apps: while GPS coordinates receives another application, my app does not receive them. When I turn off the tracking in another app, my application again starting to get the coordinates.

How to make two or more apps simultaneously received GPS coordinates. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application that is registered for location updates through a locationlistener **cannot** be responsible for another application to **not** receive location updates anymore.

When multiple apps are using the requestLocationUpdates feature, Android will start GPS tracking for these apps, and these apps will all receive GPS locations trough the locationlistener providing there's a proper GPS signal.

Comment: Thanks. I received GPS coordinates on GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX and then getLastKnownLocation.